# I want multiple variables toggled as true or false depending on the current route

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, controller, handlebars.js

I want multiple variables toggled as true or false depending on the current route, which the controller checks when the page loads.

```
VpcYeoman.SuperTableController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({  
    routedToLocations: false,
    routedToUsers: false,
    currentPath: '/',
    checkCurrentPath: function() {
      if ( currentPath == '/users')
        this.set( 'routedToUsers', true )
    } elsif ( currentPath == '/locations' ) {
        this.set( 'routedToLocations', true )
    }
});
```

superTable.hbs

```
{{#if routedToUsers}}
Users!
{{/if}}

{{#if routedToLocations}}
Locations
{{/if}}
```

in users.hbs

`{{render superTable model}} //which will result in the string 'Users!'`

in locations.hbs

`{{render superTable model}} //which will result in the string 'Locations!'`

Or maybe i could add the variables, like `routedToUsers`, inside of the 'users' controller with set values. It would look like,

```
- users_controller.js -
    routedToUsers: true,
    canBeEdited: false,
    canBeDeleted: true,
```

This way, each super-table has those variables except they are already predefined. Another example.

```
 - locations_controller.js - 
       routedToUsers: false, // this is obviously false but for example's sake
       routedToLocations: true,
       canBeEdited: false,
       canBeDeleted: false,
```

So if I clicked a `#link-to` on another page that routed me to 'users' for instance, the controller would use '`checkCurrentPath`' to make sure that I was indeed on the users page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two main groups of path changes or "`transitions`" that occur in your app.

**First:** Ember will initialize and the router will transition the user into the desired context. This can take several transitions if you have nested resources. If a user returns to a nested resource or reloads the page, Ember is smart and will reload with context. Thus, the auto-transitioning.

**Second:** The user may transition through the app based on whatever UI you cooked up.

To address the first of two issues, you will probably need to initialize each route's controller to activate the `currentPath` property, using the `setupController` hook. That way on page load the route will do the first setter, then the observer will deal with any user-based path changes.

Here is a generic path observer that you can place in your application controller. **It will address the second of the two issues**:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['super-table', 'users', 'locations'],
  currentPathDidChange: function () {
    var path_base = this.get('currentPath').split('.')[0];
    this.set('controllers.super-table.currentPath', path_base); // give your super table template the path
    this.nullifyActiveFlags(); // You can write this yourself...
    switch(path_base){ // just give me the base resource
      case 'users':
        this.set('controllers.users.activePath', true);
        break;
      case 'locations':
        this.set('controllers.locations.activePath', true);
        break;
    }
  }.observes('currentPath'),
//...
```

I would probably pull that callback logic out of the observer and into its own method, but this is just pseudo-code to show what is possible.

You should also refactor the super table `currentPath` setter to be a computed alias from within the super table controller.

Let me know if there is any additional explanation needed! I've used similar patterns quite a few times and it works very nicely when configured correctly.

Comment: 'locations' and 'users' both user the Super Table Controller, so would it make sense to add the code in this answer to that controller instead of the Application Controller? And if that's the case, then i wouldn't need to call 'needs' on super-table, right?

Comment: Nope. `currentPath` is an application controller property.

Comment: You could just call `controllers.application.currentPath` from anywhere... So I guess you can put this observer wherever you want. Sounds like it would be hard to keep things DRY that way, though.

Comment: You're right, controllers.application.currentPath does seem a little longer than it could be. What do you mean when you say that i should compute an alias from within the Super Table Controller for currentPath? Do you mean setting currentPath: '' to something like currentPath: '/locations' or '/'?

Comment: I've updated my question with a couple more lines of code at the end. I apologize for not clarifying this sooner, but I use render to create the super-table. I'm not sure if this changes anything though.

Comment: @IanSteffy You should probably create a new question. It's generally bad practice to keep adding on after answers are provided...

Comment: My answer still applies to your follow-up... not sure how I can be of further assistance. To be honest, I don't really understand what you are trying to do, I'm simply providing an abstract solution to help approach it.

Comment: I appreciate your help either way. I'm making a custom `<table>` template that can be reused in any area of my app that uses a dynamic list. So for the 'users' model for instance, all I would need to do is toss in `{{render 'superTable' model}}` in `users.hbs`, and viola! The `users.hbs` will turn into a beautiful list with full functionality since the super-table includes `edit` and `delete` actions within its controller.

Comment: A coworker of mine (@Darshan) was saying much help this one guy on stack overflow. It ended up being you. Thanks a bunch @Matthew

Comment: @IanSteffy Thank you for the kind words! Very happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, `undefined` is falsey in Javascript, so you shouldn't actually need to explicitly set it to `false`.  If you want a generic function to set the current path to `true`, just use regular expressions.  For example:

```
setCurrentPath: function() {
  this.set(("routed_to_" + currentPath.match(/\/(.*)/)[1]).camelize(), true);
}
```

As a **HUGE** caveat, I'll also add you probably shouldn't be doing any of this in the first place.  Generally, if you find yourself writing

```
if (isAThing) {
  ...
} else if (isAnotherThing) {
  ...
} else if (isYetAnotherThing) {
  ...
}
```

you might find the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) or [chain of responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) useful.

Also, placing a lot of logic in Handlebars will eat away at your performance because every time something changes, it has to manipulate your DOM.  If you need logic, keep it in Javascript and minimize the computed properties in your template.  If it's more complex that that, let your router decide what to spit out into an outlet.

It's really tough to convey tone in text, and I hope I don't come across like I'm beating up on you.  Just trying to pass on some hard-learned lessons.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Travis. This answer also worked! Yes, I had tried making this super flexible template for anything in my App that used a list and it used a TON of handlebar #if conditionals that created and destroyed every aspect of this template depending on what the current data was at the time. This had serious performance issues.