# I want an action that links me to the Object clicked in a list of Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a simple action that can be attached to list items in an `{{#each}}` loop, and when that action is triggered, **it will link to that instance of the model**.

This is what it looks like now

```
VpcYeoman.SuperTableController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    goTo: function(input) {
      this.transitionToRoute('someModel', input);
    }
  } 
});
```

The action is called on an HTML element like this

```
{{action 'goTo' this bubbles=false}}
```

You can see the problem with this in that 'goTo' cannot be reused on other models because it is specifically looking at the 'someModel' model.

**Please help me make this action work for whatever the current model is**

I tried replacing 'someModel' with a generic 'model' & even 'this.model' but they didn't work.

---

Do not reply with 'use {{#link-to}}' please. I am aware that this exists and

Comment: where is your code that attaches `goTo` to your list items?  (and where is the second half of your question?  it ends in the middle of a sentence...)

Comment: What is `someModel` supposed to be? I can write you some pseudo code. Computed property or even a simple function would suffice here... You need to figure out how to use the model context to determine that route path.

Comment: currently `someModel` is replaced by `users` in my code. So clicking a user in a list of users will link to that user, and as it is now, that works fine, but the problem is that I don't want to have to rewrite my goTo action multiple times in one controller. The controller is the 'SuperTableController' that I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871938/i-want-multiple-variables-toggled-as-true-or-false-depending-on-the-current-route. With this controller, i'm trying to make global actions that deal with all of the basic `edit`, `delete` `link to this` functionality

Comment: Sorry, `someModel` is replaced by `user` not `users`. `users` will give me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you read this, you should know that I do recommend you use the link-to helper. I normally pass a computed property to the helper when I need it to change based on the model...

I am not sure where you have that action in your code, but you could just compute that path as needed. For example, take this item controller:

```
App.ItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  getTransitionPath: function () {
    return this.get('foo') + '_bar';
  },

  transitionPath: function () {
    return this.get('foo') + '_bar';
  }.property('foo'),

  actions: {
    goTo: function(input) {
      //this.transitionToRoute(this.getTransitionPath(), input); // Regular method
      this.transitionToRoute(this.get('transitionPath'), input); // Computed property
    }
  }
});
```

I also don't know what kind of logic you are looking for inside of those methods, but this pattern should work on a per model basis.

Good luck!

Comment: I ran into issues with `{{#link-to}}` where it made assumptions that I want all of my text to be in blue and sometimes, depending on how much or what HTML was inside of `{{#link-to}}{{/link-to}}` tags, it didn't work at all. So I build my own action. I've just updated my question.

Comment: What is 'foo' and '_bar' supposed to represent? `model` ?

Comment: Just showing how you could use a property of the current model to return a dynamic string.

Comment: I got it finally! Thanks Matthew!

Comment: @IanSteffy Sweet! Happy I could help.