# I want my function to be triggered when the route changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ember.js

I have a function that changes the css of a class and I want that function to be called **anytime that the route changes**. I also want this logic to be placed inside the ApplicationView so it will be called anywhere at anytime the route changes.

The class that is being altered by the function (we'll call that class `.float-right-col`) is created once on every `.hbs` template in my app.

```
<div class="float-right-col">
</div>
```

The **pseudo code** of what I want

```
Whenever we are transitioned to a new route {
  Set the css of float-right-col to this by toggle classes with overriding attributes
}
```

**Information that I left out for simplicity's sake (optional)** AKA The Big Picture:

Eventually the pseudo code mentioned above will have another condition `&&` that requires the screen to be > 800px.

```
Whenever we are transitioned to a new route {
  check if the screen size is below 800px & if it is {
    Set the css of float-right-col to this
  }
}
```

Ideally the css would just know the screen size and adjust the css before the page loads.
With this pseudo code above, the page will load with the default css, and then the function will be called which makes float-right-col transition into a new position.

To toggle the css of this element i add and remove these two classes to `.float-right-col`.

```
 .openCol {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0px;
    transition: all .2s ease 0s;
  }
  .closeCol {
    position:fixed;
    right: -290px;
    transition: all .2s ease 0s;
  }
```

I've also tried using .css()

Finally, I've tried media queries, but those seem to only work on the initial load of the first page

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .float-right-col {
    position: fixed !important;
    right: -290px;
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "route changes" ?

Comment: As long as you have the same Style-sheet file for all your "routes" the media queries should work on every "route". If you are using SPA and want to throw an event as soon as the "route" changes, you should take a look into the API of your framework it probably exposes such an event. Another way to go would be to use `setInterval`and check whether `window.location` has changed and throw the event yourself.

Comment: @LinuxN00b I do mention the framework in the tags. Ember.js

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez When the url changes. So linking from users.hbs -> locations.hbs

Comment: @Kevkong I do have the same style-sheet for every route and it does NOT work. Could you clarify what SPA is?

Comment: SPA = Single Page Application. The Page is loaded once and every navigation triggers an Ajax call to get the new content. Do you have an example for the media queries not working? Maybe take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815651/why-is-my-css-media-query-being-ignored-or-overridden

Comment: Thanks @Kevkong ! The media query example is the last example in the OP, unless you mean something else.

Comment: I meant something like a example webpage or fiddle where I can use my browser to debug and take a look, why the media queries wouldn't work.

Comment: This looks familiar... http://stackoverflow.com/a/24873276/614152 :D

Comment: Yes you did provide an answer, but I was unable to get it to work. I ended up using a component. And just today I was thinking 'i hope matthew doesnt think i blew off his answer'. My project has a deadline which accounts for my delay, but don't worry, I will address that similar question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could observe the `currentPath` in the ApplicationController and react on any changes.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentPathChanged: function() {
    console.log(this.get('currentPath'));
  }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

Comment: This works! One problem I'm having is that when I route to the root '/', it doesn't think that I'm changing routes. Is there a good work-around to this?

Comment: Sorry for being such a jsbin noob, but i can't seem to get it to work. I'm also seeing this css change NOT occur in other pages like `/users`, but in `/records`, it DOES works. I think I've narrowed down the problem though. The function is being called everytime I change routes, but perhaps it is thinking that the `.float-right-col` in `users` im calling with Jquery  is not the same `float-right-col` that's in `/users`

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish something like that? https://google-developers.appspot.com/web/fundamentals/resources/samples/layouts/navigation-patterns/appbar-navdrawer-bottombar-sample . Resize your browser window to see the effect.

Comment: Yes, with the sidebar in that example. I use `right` to push the columns partly off the screen when the screen is smaller.

Comment: Then I would recommend you the web fundamentals on multi device layouts. https://google-developers.appspot.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/ . In your case media queries would be the `right way` to solve the problem.